# ASP.NET Core MVC - How to persist shopping basket data without sessions

Tags: asp.net-core, persistence, shopping-cart

in my previous projects, I had used inherited controllers to persist data across my last project e.g.

```
public class UsersController : ProjectAController
{
```

Although I added custom data to the base controller, e.g. shopping cart, alerts, wishlists etc

These values are values that are loaded in the _Layout page (and are loaded once from the database, instead of repetitive round trip coding

What is best practices ?

thanks

Ehi

Comment: You could still use `Session` to manage this data...I think it just works slightly differently in .NET Core (https://benjii.me/2016/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnetcore-and-mvc-core/). Data could be Serialised with JSON. Alternatively maybe you could use `localStorage` to hold data between submits.

Comment: Sessions dont handle well on enterprise users.